# Migrate nested extra properties from .gradle to .gradle.kts (DSL)

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Creating example:

```
ext {
    versions = [
            kotlin     : "1.3.72",

            application: [
                    versionName     : getVersionName(),
                    versionCode     : getVersionCode(),
                    imageVersionCode: getImageVersionCode(),
            ],
            android    : [
                    compileSdk: 29,
                    minSdk    : 21,
                    targetSdk : 29,
                    java      : JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8,
            ],
    ]
}
```

Using example

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.android.compileSdk
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion versions.android.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion versions.android.targetSdk
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I [found](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html) examples without nesting for .kts:

```
val springVersion by extra("3.1.0.RELEASE")
val emailNotification by extra { "build@master.org" }
```

But I can't find any documentation to write this code on Kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here

```
val versions by extra( mapOf(
    "kotlin" to "1.3.72",
    "application" to mapOf(
        "versionName" to project.version,
        "versionCode" to project.version,
        "imageVersionCode" to project.version
    ),
    "android" to mapOf(
        "compileSdk" to 29,
        "minSdk" to 21,
        "targetSdk" to 29,
        "java" to JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    )
))
```